# The @MessagingGateway annotated interface is not getting registered as bean to spring IOC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I'm using Spring integration scatter-gather pattern, the configuration is being done by using java dsl. I've a Gateway interface which is annotated with @MessagingGateway and has a method which is annotated as @Gateway. When I'm trying to fire this gateway in controller by Autowiring the interface it's throwing error.

The error is -

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field lionGateway in com.example.core.controller.LionController required a bean of type 'com.example.core.service.LionGateway' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Config class -
Package - com.example.common.config

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {
  @Autowired LoansServiceImpl loansService;

  long dbId = new SequenceGenerator().nextId();
  //   Main flow
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.split()
            .log()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .convert(LoanProvisionRequest.class)
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                        .recipientFlow(flow2())
                        .recipientFlow(flow3()),
                gatherer -> gatherer.releaseLockBeforeSend(true))
            .log()
            .aggregate(a -> a.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getMessages))
            .channel("output-flow");
  }
  //   flow1
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
    return integrationFlowDefination ->
        integrationFlowDefination
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                message -> {
                  try {
                    lionService.saveLionRequest(
                        (LionRequest) message.getPayload(), String.valueOf(dbId));
                  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                  }
                });
  }

  //   flow2
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
    return integrationFlowDefination ->
        integrationFlowDefination
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                message ->
                    lionService.getData(
                        (LionRequest) message.getPayload(), SourceSystem.PROVISION))
            .log();
  }

  //  flow3
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow3() {
    return integrationFlowDefination ->
        integrationFlowDefination
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                message ->
                    lionService.prepareCDRequest(
                        (LionRequest) message));
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor("output-flow", outputExecutor()).get();
  }

  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor outputExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(4);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    return pool;
  }
}
```

Gateway Interface -
package  - com.example.core.service

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface LionGateway {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "flow.input", replyChannel = "output-flow")
  List<?> echo(LionRequest lionRequest);
}
```

Controller -
package - com.example.core.controller

```
@Autowired private LionGateway lionGateway;

 @PostMapping(value = "/invoke-integration")
  public String invokeIntegrationFlow(@RequestBody LionRequest lionRequest) {
    String response = lionGateway.echo(lionRequest).toString();
    return response;
  }
```

Main class - package - com.example

Comment: Would be great to have some simple project from you to reproduce and play with. Doesn't look like default `@SpringBootApplication` should fail somehow with the structure you provide so far...

Comment: Do you have `@IntegrationComponentScan` on one of your `@Configuration` classes?

Comment: Spring Boot provides an auto-configuration for that, unless this is very old version…

Comment: No Gary Russell I haven't declared @IntegrationComponentScan in any of my class.

Comment: I think we can't have dsl and xml config at the same time in one project, is it so?

Comment: We can, but annotations must be first. I mean your xml has to be add as an `@ImportResource`.  I don’t see how it is relevant to the code you show above …